# SQL delete on group by conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

A cursor is used, but it's slow and appears to be a big bottleneck in a SQL job. Basically, this is a cleanup effort to remove all but the top X accessories (ordered by sales rank) from a particular source that's previously grouped by a product id and account visibility.

The command is basically built in the each iteration of the cursor loop and `exec`'ed manually.

The `vis` column refers to multiple tenants that sort of acts like a bitmask e.g. two tenants could have the same product.

```
declare @prodid int
declare @cnt    int
declare @vis    bigint
declare @cmd    varchar(600)
declare @clause varchar(600)

-- find records with more than X excess accessories
declare cur cursor for
    select pa.prodid, 'cnt' = count(*), vis from [accessories] pa
    group by prodid, vis
    having count(*) > X -- e.g. 5
```

Sample output could look like

```
prodid  cnt     vis
123     6       128
234     8       260
345     10      512
```

In the case where X=5, the last 1 `salesrank` item for 123 would be removed, the last 3 for 234 and the last 5 for 345. **Can this be done using a `DELETE` statement while including the groupings in some nested select?**

```
open cur

fetch next from cur into @prodid, @cnt, @vis
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    -- a clause that ends up looking like this:
    -- 12345 and vis = 128 -- OR -- 23456 and vis is null   
    set @clause = convert(varchar(14), @prodid) + ' and vis ' + case 
        when @vis is null then ' is null ' 
        else ' = ' + cast(@vis as varchar) end

    -- delete all but the top X from source=2 and that match prodid and vis
    set @cmd = 'delete from [accessories] 
        where source = 2 and prodid=' + @clause +
        ' and access_prodid in (select top ' + convert(varchar(5), @cnt - X) + 
        ' access_prodid from [accessories] where prodid = ' 
        + @clause + ' and source = 2 order by salesrank)'

    exec(@cmd)
    fetch next from cur into @prodid, @cnt, @vis
end 
close cur
deallocate cur
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH DupData AS
(
    SELECT  *,
      ROW_NUMBER() 
          OVER(PARTITION BY pa.prodid, pa.vis ORDER BY salesrank) Position
      FROM [accessories] pa
      WHERE pa.source = 2
)
DELETE 
    FROM DupData
 WHERE Position > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by using windows functions to identify the rows to be deleted:

```
with t as (select pa.*,
                  row_number() over (partition by prodid, vis order b salesrank) as sr
           from [accessories] pa
          )
delete from pa
from t
where pa.prodid = t.prodid and pa.vis = t.vis and pa.salesrank = t.salesrank
```

If there is a unique id in the pa table, then you can use that instead of the more complicated where statement.  This assumes that salesrank is unique within each prodid/vis group.